# Cannot Cover Value of type countable closedRange<int>to expected argument type Rang <int>

Tags: swift, swift3

**Please help how to solve this error in swift3**

```
 let max:Int = Int(StackMaxWidth/10)
 let min:Int = Int(StackMinWidth/10)
 let width:CGFlot = CGFlot(randomInRange(min...max)*10)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk3aJ.png)

```
func randomInRange(_ range: Range<Int>) -> Int {
let count = UInt32(range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)
return  Int(arc4random_uniform(count)) + range.lowerBound
```

}
This is one type of function

Comment: What is `randomInRange()`? Where is it defined? What arguments does it take? – We cannot *guess* your code.

Comment: It's function which is return range

Answer (score 0):

replace `self.StackGapMinWidth...maxGap` to `self.StackGapMinWidth..<(maxGap + 1)`